# WMI Files Montioring using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, wmi

I am working on **WMI(Windows Management Instrumentation)** in **C#** and stuck at a point.

I have to create an application using **WMI (C#)** similar to *File System Watcher.*

I would like to get notified every time whenever within a particular folder a new file is created or deleted.

MY WQL query is :

```
SELECT * from _InstanceModificationEvent within 2 where TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' and TargetInstance.Drive = 'C:' AND TargetInstance.Path='\\Test'
```

While running the query using *wbemtest* , it displays an Error message prompting Invalid Class.

Can someone please help me out regarding same?

Comment: Is it a typo in [`_InstanceModificationEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394651(v=vs.85).aspx)? There should be 2 underscores as a prefix.

Comment: Yes thank you,Also the query has to run in Notification query rather than as a simple query.
But still process hangs up rather executing.Can you provide some solution??

Answer (score 2):

In order to detect when a file is created , modified or deleted you must use the [`__InstanceOperationEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394652%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI Class and the using the value of `__Class` property you can figure out out if the file was modified, deleted o created.

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;


namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    public class EventWatcherAsync
    {
        private void WmiEventHandler(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // e.NewEvent
            string wclass = ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent).SystemProperties["__Class"].Value.ToString();
            string wop = string.Empty;
            switch (wclass)
            {
                case "__InstanceModificationEvent":
                    wop = "Modified";
                    break;
                case "__InstanceCreationEvent":
                    wop = "Created";
                    break;
                case "__InstanceDeletionEvent":
                    wop = "Deleted";
                    break;
            }
            string wfilename = ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["FileName"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["Extension"].ToString()))
            {
                wfilename += "." + ((ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"].Value)["Extension"].ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The File {0} was {1}", wfilename, wop));


        }

        public EventWatcherAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                string WmiQuery;
                ManagementEventWatcher Watcher;
                ManagementScope Scope;


                if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                    Conn.Username = "";
                    Conn.Password = "";
                    Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
                }
                else
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);
                Scope.Connect();
                //Check for changes in the path C:\Test
                WmiQuery = @"Select * From __InstanceOperationEvent Within 1 
                Where TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' and TargetInstance.Drive = 'C:' AND TargetInstance.Path='\\Test\\'";

                Watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, new EventQuery(WmiQuery));
                Watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(this.WmiEventHandler);
                Watcher.Start();
                Console.Read();
                Watcher.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }

        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening {0}", "__InstanceOperationEvent");
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            EventWatcherAsync eventWatcher = new EventWatcherAsync();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks RRUZ, This is what I was searching for :)